# How To Convert JSON String That Contains Encoded Unicode

Tags: json, unicode, decode

Could anyone tell me how to convert the following json object string, which contains encoded unicode characters (Chinese in this case) to human readable one using c# in asp.net?

```
records:[{"description":"\u849c\u8089","id":282}]
```

The string is submitted via Ajax from an Ext JS web application.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to convert this string in any special manner. Any JSON decoder that more or less sticks to the specification will automatically create a correct string for the *description* attribute.

**Update:**

However, your current sample is not valid JSON. It's missing brackets or braces around the complete sample and it's missing double qutoes around *records*.

A correct JSON snippet would be:

```
{"records":[{"description":"\u849c\u8089","id":282}]}
```

Giving:

- records:

  - []

    - description: 蒜肉
    - id: 282

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Which JSON decoder would you recommend?

Comment: There's .NET's built-in [Json serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) and there's the poplular [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). I can recommend both for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it should be done as follows:

```
var  bytes  =  Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("<unicode string>"); 
//  Return  the  Base64-encoded  string.  
string  str  =    Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```